# SQL selecting number based on date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data below:

```
 Numbers     Effdate     End_date
2017937950  10/31/2010  4/8/2014 11:59:59 PM
2017937950  10/31/2010  6/30/2011 11:59:59 PM
4054631308  5/9/2008    12/31/2099
4054631308  5/9/2008    7/14/2009 11:59:59 PM
7062329778  10/28/2009  12/31/2099
7062329778  10/28/2009  11/10/2009 11:59:59 PM
```

I need to pick only those Numbers which has end_date 12/31/2099,
so the data looks like below data:

```
  Numbers     Effdate     End_date
4054631308  5/9/2008    12/31/2099
4054631308  5/9/2008    7/14/2009 11:59:59 PM
7062329778  10/28/2009  12/31/2099
7062329778  10/28/2009  11/10/2009 11:59:59 PM
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Looks like `where number in` or `where exists` would do the trick or a `INNER join on a subquery` which returns the numbers of those having that end date joining on number.  I would think where exists might be best performance but depends on indexes, and data volumn

Comment: I have tried exists and it gives me only one number associated with 12/31/2099 not other number though

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE end_date=yourdatehere`

Answer (score 1):

You an select the related rows using in  clause

```
 select * from my_table 
 where numbers in (select distinct numbers from my_table 
                     where end_date  = to_date('12/31/2099', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

Comment: Why do you use subquery? Single `Select` statement with `Where` codndition should be enough!

Comment: For getting only the numbers requested you should use a subquery or a join .. in this case the subquery is more simple ..

Comment: @MaciejLos He wants to return all the rows for a set of numbers that has that end date. Not return just the rows for that end date. See his example output.

Comment: @SQLChao  exact .. he don'wont the row that match the date but the row with the same numbers that in a row match the date

Comment: @scaisEdge I know... I was explaining to maciejlos.

Comment: @SQLChao  you answer was right .. undelete please is like mine .. (on the date format ... but is a minor)

Comment: @scaisEdge Yours is right and I like the format date. We don't need two basically same answer.

Comment: @SQLChao  .. is not a race  if you answer is right like mine is fair rate as useful also your answer ..

Answer (score 0):

Using an exists: fastest usually; but only allows access to the data in one of the tables.

```
Select Numbers, EffDate, End_Date 
from table B
where exists (Select 1 from table A 
              where A.end_Date = to_date('12/31/2099', 'DD/MM/YYYY')  
                 and A.Numbers= B.Numbers)
```

Using a join: (allows access to all columns of both tables joined.

```
Select Numbers, EffDate, End_Date 
from table B
INNER JOIN (Select Distinct Numbers from table 
            where end_date = to_date('12/31/2099', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using an analytic function:

```
with sample_data as (select 2017937950 Numbers, to_date('10/31/2010', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Effdate, to_date('04/08/2015 23:59:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') End_date from dual union all
                     select 2017937950 Numbers, to_date('10/31/2010', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Effdate, to_date('04/08/2015 23:59:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') End_date from dual union all
                     select 4054631308 Numbers, to_date('05/09/2008', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Effdate, to_date('12/31/2099 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') End_date from dual union all
                     select 4054631308 Numbers, to_date('05/09/2008', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Effdate, to_date('07/14/2009 23:59:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') End_date from dual union all
                     select 7062329778 Numbers, to_date('10/28/2009', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Effdate, to_date('12/31/2099 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') End_date from dual union all
                     select 7062329778 Numbers, to_date('10/28/2009', 'mm/dd/yyyy') Effdate, to_date('11/10/2009 23:59:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') End_date from dual)
select numbers,
       effdate,
       end_date
from   (select numbers,
               effdate,
               end_date,
               max(end_date) over (partition by numbers) max_end_date
        from   sample_data)
where  max_end_date = to_date('12/31/2099', 'mm/dd/yyyy');

   NUMBERS EFFDATE               END_DATE             
---------- --------------------- ---------------------
4054631308 05/09/2008 00:00:00   12/31/2099 00:00:00  
4054631308 05/09/2008 00:00:00   07/14/2009 23:59:59  
7062329778 10/28/2009 00:00:00   12/31/2099 00:00:00  
7062329778 10/28/2009 00:00:00   11/10/2009 23:59:59
```